# how to download csv format data from api's response using anchor tag download - React

Tags: reactjs

Does someone have exp, to download data from api's response useing anchor tag.

API return file format.

got it, API return text/csv format

```
  const handleDownload = async () => {
    const { data } = await API.exportExcel();
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], { type: `text/csv` }));
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute("download", "file name");
    link.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created your element, but you haven't pushed it to the DOM. And the click function only works if an element is present in the DOM.

```js
  const handleDownload = async () => {
    const { data } = await API.exportExcel();
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], { type: `text/csv` }));
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute("download", "file name");
    // Changed line below
    document.body.appendChild(link); // This will add your link to the DOM
    // ------------------
    link.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    link.remove(); // This will remove the link from DOM after completion of the process.
  };
```